# Building Irregular terrain in tile-based approach

Tags: tiles, transparency, collision-avoidance

I'm starting to build a 2D game, metroidvania-like, tile-based and all. I've had some prior experience in it, and one of the major letdowns of those prior games was that worlds seemed too "blockish", kinda inorganic, when they shouldn't (underground caverns aren't squarish at all). So, for this time, I'm trying to come up with a way to build a world just like Cave Story's:

[image]

It has some nice angles and feels way better than a purely tiled world.

As far as I know, SP built this world using AS2 back in 2002, when computers hadn't all the processing power they have today, so I think he haven't used any kind of heavy mask to do it. Talking with one of my teachers, he suggested the guy used raycasts to search for non-transparent pixels in rectangular tiles. Dunno if it's true, but I decided to get further help through here. I'd like some suggestions for a nice and soft approach to this kind of work, if possible.

Comment: Check out this link for a place to start http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/

Comment: Nice post, I implemented a game using bitmask. When my hero walk, the game calculates if he can climb a angled. As a worms the scenario also were destructive. I think in nowsday the vectorial approach are better and less expensive to do.

Comment: yay o/
I've already seen this link before, I believe thrice, great text. It convinced me before that vectorial should be the way to go now, but then I started to think at how large my art should get to match the collider's curves. I'll do some research and possibly come with some conclusion after it.